# Jboss Data Grid forFor Apache/Jetty

Tags: jboss, grid, jboss7.x

How can I configure Jboss Data grid to use Apache and jetty? I have requirement where I was asked to configure Apache to jboss Data grid and then Jetty. I am running out of options and can't find any online help for documentation.

All that I get Googling is configuring jboss EAP with Jboss Data Grid.

The Flow is

Apache (Static Pages) ->Jboss Data Grid -> Jetty

Comment: I don't think you can deploy an EAR to Jetty. I'm not 100% certain about that, but Jetty is a servlet container not a Java EE container.

Comment: True , i have edited my comment :)